# What is the use of 2nd device selection drop down in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In android studio flutter project, what is the use of this 2nd device selection drop down?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is for running the same app on multiple devices at once, i have not used that feature but that's what i found.